# Inserting Data into multiple SQL tables with foreign key constraints using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

As the title suggests, I am looking for solutions to add data to multiple tables that have FK constraints all on one form.

Basically I click the magic button and it fires the data over to the relevant tables. See the screenshot for table relationships so you can see the general idea:

[image: Table relationships]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2oIa.png)

I am getting this error:

> Cannot insert NULL into BookingID

for the `Payments` table. This is a FK relationship, but basically when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the Windows form, I want it to generate the primary key in the `Booking` table and link it so it saves it all as one booking.

I have inserted an image of the actual booking screen (it's very basic at the moment) but it highlights the tables etc.

[image: This image is a look at the program]

I am trying to figure out how i can explain this in a better way, so sorry if it is not very clear. But Basically, The bookings table has `CustomerID` and `PaymentsID` FK's in it. When I press enter, I want it to send the data over so that if I ran a query on the specific booking ID it would display all the information (Cust name, Payments etc).

Oh and I am doing the Windows Forms in C# which I am very very new to so please be gentle with me.

I was asked to upload some code so here is a little bit. The problem I have is I have no idea how to handle FK constraints using C#.

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Payments (PaymentMethod, PaymentAmount, PaymentDate, PaymentReceived, Discount) VALUES (@PayMethod,@Cost,@PayDate,@PaymentReceived,@Discount)"))
{
    cmd.Connection = con;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PayMethod", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PayMeth.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cost", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Cost.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PayDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = PayDatePick.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PaymentReceived", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = PayReceived.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Discount", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DiscountText.Text;

    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Record inserted");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Payment failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have already tried. It's hard to debug without the source code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, i have uploaded the code to insert data into the Payments table. but I have no idea how to handle FK constraints with c#

Comment: Your didn't show us how the `Payments` table looks like. From the error message, it seems that there is a `BookingID` in the `Payments` table and you didn't pass in any value while inserting.

Comment: Hi, Yes that's the problem. So when the user clicks the submit button, It will generate a BookingID in the Booking table in the DBS, however it is not adding that BookingID into the Payments table either. In other words it is not copying over the ID as a FK so that it is all linked.

Answer (score -1):

Is your Booking.BookingId an auto increment or Unique field?

If not when you insert the booking record, you will need to set the value (so its not null).